# How to scale the spacing between controls in a stack panel to fit a window?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, uno-platform, winui

I am wanting to create a horizontal stackpanel (or something similar) that will scale the spacing of different sized controls so that the spacing between them is the same but they span the entire window.
Psuedo-Code:

```
<!--Something Like This: -->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Spacing="Max">
        <TextBlock Text="Thing that is number 1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Thing 2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Number 3"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Thing that 4"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I am using uno platform, which uses a sort of hybrid of winui and uwp if I understand correctly, and might make some things not work. [https://platform.uno/docs/articles/api-differences.html#:~:text=Uno%20Platform%20strives%20to%20closely,is%20100%25%20compatible%20with%20Uno](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/api-differences.html#:%7E:text=Uno%20Platform%20strives%20to%20closely,is%20100%25%20compatible%20with%20Uno).

I haven't been able to find anything that works yet. I tried to get DockPanel to work but it didn't (both dockpanel and controls:dockpanel). From what it looks like from this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.spacing?view=winrt-22621, spacing only accepts a double, but I could very well be wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your control only TextBlock inside the panel? If so, it is recommended to use [ItemsRepeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/items-repeater).

Comment: No I was just using them as examples. I plan on putting both text and buttons in the stackpanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [UniformGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid) control from the **WindowsCommunityToolkit**.

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="UniformGridExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UniformGridExample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <toolkit:UniformGrid
        Columns="3"
        FirstColumn="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Rows="1">
        <Border
            BorderBrush="HotPink"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Button Content="1" />
        </Border>
        <Border
            BorderBrush="LightGreen"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Button Content="2" />
        </Border>
        <Border
            BorderBrush="SkyBlue"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Button Content="3" />
        </Border>
    </toolkit:UniformGrid>
</Page>
```

You also can see how it's implemented [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/7.1.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives/UniformGrid).

Comment: When I tried this it threw this error: XLS0414 The type 'controls:UniformGrid' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. I did add the namespace from the first link: xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls".

Comment: Sorry, my answer was the sample code from the docs and it was for UWP. The correct namespace is *CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls*. I updated my answer with a simpler example. Anyway, you also need to install the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Primitives](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Primitives/7.1.2?_src=template) NuGet package. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)'s how you can install NuGet packages.

Comment: The uno platform has their own nuget packages, Uno.CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Primitives, that are based off of the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Primitives, but it is made to be cross platform. I found a page on their docs that shows how to use it. Thanks for the help!